# Spring MVC 3 JSF 2 with Maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, jsf, jsf-2

im trying to use JSF composite componets in my spring3 aplication.

Following error is comming :

```
    WARNING: Unable to load class [javax.servlet.jsp.el.ImplicitObjectELResolver$EnumeratedMap] to check against the @HandlesTypes annotation of one or more ServletContentInitializers. 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.jsp.el.ImplicitObjectELResolver$EnumeratedMap
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.checkHandlesTypes(ContextConfig.java:1956)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:1919)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1806)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1765)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1751)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1255)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:882)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:317)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5081)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:774)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:620)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:431)
```

THis is the my Project Structure :

[image: THis is the my Project Structure :]

I have just copied the code from the below link .... can any help me why i am getting this error....

http://papweb.wordpress.com/2011/07/29/spring-mvc-3-jsf-2-with-maven-2-and-tomcat/

and i am also getting the warning in faces-config like which shown in the below link :

[Class org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver must extend the type javax.el.ELResolver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201021/warning-in-faces-config-xml-integrating-spring-with-jsf)

Answer (score 2):

It would have been helpful to resolve if you had given your POM.xml because the exception clearly shows it cannot find necessary classes

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.jsp.el.ImplicitObjectELResolver
```

Check if you have dependencies for `javax.servlet.jsp-api` and `javax.el-api` in your pom.xml or add the below maven dependencies

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
       <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
       <version>2.2.2</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: Still it is showing the same error... Plz help me what should i do ?

Comment: please provide your pom.xml as I've mentioned in my answer